# Angular 2: Update list from other view using a service (http + json)

Tags: angularjs, angular, service, ionic-framework

My first post here so: Hi! Stuck with an Ionic 2 (2.1.0-beta.1)/Angular 2 question which I hope you guys can help me with:

My basic setup is:

- page 1 with "favorites" list
- second page with search + possibility to add one of the results to list from page 1

To access the object from both pages I am using a service.

First page html with favorites directly referring to service object.

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let fav of stationsService.favs">
    {{fav.image}}
</ion-list>
```

In the constructor of the service I am getting the present favorites.

```
@
Injectable()
export class stationsService {
    public headers: Headers;
    public favs: any;

constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.getFavorites()
        .subscribe(data => {
        this.favs = data;
        });
}
getFavorites() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/favorite_stations')
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

... which works. When I now go to the search page and add a item to the list the data is updated (post works) but the list is still the same once I go back. Here is my add function from the service.

```
    addFavorite(station) {
        return this.http
        .post('http://localhost:3000/favorite_stations', station, {
        headers: this.headers
        })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
        this.favs.push(data);
        });
    }
```

Any idea what my mistake might be? Thanks!

Comment: Are you making a get call to your factory every time the favorites page loads?

Comment: I guess thats the problem... How would I do that? ngOnInit() fires just once.

Comment: I resolved the issue working with one page hiding the list dependent on the state. Thanks!